# Local server outside: How to access url internal over router?

Tags: routing, url, email-server

i have the following problem: i installed a new test-mailserver in our office today and did some port-forwarding on our router to the specific mailserver ports. everything works fine, except the following situation:

i want to use a url foo.bar.at, whos a-record points to our fix network ip. this work fine when checking mails out of our office, but when trying in the local wifi, the url canÄt be accessed because of the router.

the problem is: on our iphones i only want to use ONE url to check the mails in the wifi AND outside of our office-network.

any advice here how this can be fixed?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

- "NAT Reflection" is the term for getting your router to do the NAT for the outside address for traffic originating internally.  How this is configured (or whether it can be) depends completely on your router.
- DNS view splitting.  For this, you'd configure your DNS for internal systems to resolve the external name to the internal address, as opposed to letting them resolve the public address.  This depends on having a way to override that record for internal clients - what's your DNS configuration look like?

Comment: actually we use our providers dns servers. is it possible to use our own, add this specific domain and redirect the other requests to our providers server? thanks!

Comment: Yes, absolutely; you can accomplish this with any of the common DNS server packages.